# NodeJS and Socket.IO version

Tags: node.js, socket.io, installation, raspberry-pi

i want to install socketio on my raspberry pi and i want to ask which node version i need for socketio 1.0? because on the website of nodejs stands that some node apps need special versions

~MrJoki007

Comment: Just use the latest stable version.

Answer (score -1):

Do you plan to use special some special feature? As far as you get the right version for your rasPberry, last socket.io just work well with last node

Comment: i only want to connect to it with a website and javascript

Comment: can i ask you 1 more question? i found this script on the web but it doesnt work. it only returns error undefined and disconnects again when i want to connect to the socket. whats wrong?
[link](http://pastebin.com/6JpWKeJ2)

Comment: Hmm maybe you missing some node_modules? Try npm install socket.io

Comment: but that is right is it? the folder node_modules and the script is in the / folder